# Events are not being triggered inside Iframes

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

Events are not being triggered inside the iFrames.

Already existing element with css styles.

```
let div = document.getElementById('mychatbot');
```

Trying to create new iframe and dynamically add the existing content to this frame.

```
let iframe = document.getElementById('chatbot-embed');
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Now i'm getting the chatbot contents inside the `iframe` elements. There is no problem with UI. But i have added some click events in chatbot child elements.

Those events are not triggered after appended to the `iframe`. I knew that, Javascript events can be trigged only on same document window.

Is there any other way to trigger the already existing events?

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried to listen to the click event in your iframe?